# What's the probability of only one of the two students takes a certain class?

Tags: probability

A school has 150 pupils and it is offering 2 language classes: one in Spanish & one in French. There are 80 in the Spanish class and 70 in the French class. These figures include 15 students that are taking both Spanish and French.

1. Probability that they are not taking any languages?
2. Probability they are only taking spanish?
3. If a student is taking french, what is the probability they are taking spanish as well?
4. If two students are chosen randomly, what is the probability that only one of them is taking French?

**My attempt/answer**

I think the answer to

1. $0$
2. $\dfrac{80-15}{150} = \dfrac{65}{150} = 0.4333$
3. $\dfrac{15}{150} = \dfrac{1}{10} = 0.1$

but I cannot figure out the 4. question
I am very lost. Even hints in the right direction would be appreciated. TIA.

Comment: I doubt your answers to 1 and 3 are what is expected, though your answer to 2 looks like what I would have said.

Comment: What is your reason for saying $0$ to question 1?

Comment: On question 3, there are $70$ in the French class, but you do not seem to have used this information.

Comment: Use inclusion-exclusion

Comment: My answer for 1 is honestly just stupidity and taking the question at face value and not understanding what was asked. It was my first probability class. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If there are $150$ pupils and $80$ take Spanish and $70$ take French, that does not automatically imply that every pupil takes one of the two language classes.  You are also told that $15$ pupils are taking both.  This means $80 - 15 = 65$ pupils are taking *only* Spanish and not also French; and $70 - 15 = 55$ pupils are taking *only* French and not also Spanish.

With this understanding, how many pupils take neither language class?  It is *not* zero.

My suggestion is to make a table:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& \text{Taking Spanish} & \text{Not taking Spanish} & \text{Total} \\
\hline
\text{Taking French} & 15 & ? & 70 \\
\hline
\text{Not taking French} & ? & ? & ? \\
\hline
\text{Total} & 80 & ? & 150 \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

Now you must fill out the entries labeled "$?$" so that the sum of the entries in each column and row equals the corresponding total value in the respective column or row.  For instance, I already gave you the value $65$ for pupils taking Spanish but not French, and we have $15 + 65 = 80$ for the first column.

Regarding the last part of the question, we require exactly one pupil to be taking French, and the other cannot be taking French.  There are $70$ pupils who take French and $?$ who do not.  So if we pick these two pupils in order, either the first pupil is taking French and the second is not, and there are $70 \,\times\, ?$ ways to select two such pupils.  Or, the first pupil is not taking French and the second is taking French, which counts another $? \, \times \, 70$ ways, for a total of $2 \times 70 \, \times \, ?$ possible ways to pick these two pupils, out of a total $150 \times 149$ ways to select two pupils at random without replacement.

Comment: Thank you for this I made myself very confused I now understand where I went wrong. I tried to draw the table above but couldn't get it to make sense. Thank you again for the clear explanation I now understand what was asked.

Comment: F         15 55     70
not F        65 15     80
Total 80 70     150

Sorry, my table wouldn't add to this but I think this is it.  
For questions 4 is this inclusion-exclusion that the person above has mentioned. Also does the order matter? It also doesnt mention anything about replacement so can this be assumed. 
So would it be correct to use this formula or am I missing something 
P(1 taking french) = (P(F) * P(Not S)) + (P(not F)*P(S))

Answer (score 0):

For the **first question**, you seem to think that because $80$ students are taking Spanish and $70$ are taking French, all $150$ students are taking one or the other.

But that's not true. $15$ students, as the question states, are taking both. The presence of these students common to the two classes means the total number of students taking these classes is less than the sum of $80$ and $70$ (or $150$). That would mean there are students who are *not* taking either of the classes.

I suggest you use a Venn diagram or a table (as *heropup* has shown in their answer) to figure out the number of such students.

For the **third question**, we are told that the student is taking French. That means we don't have to care about all $150$ students but only the $70$ that are in the French class. And $15$ of those in the French class are taking Spanish as well. So the answer would be $15/70$.

For the **fourth question**, I don't have anything to add to what's already there in *heropup's* answer.